# Some hexa values not outputting

Tags: assembly, x86

I made this program that will output the ascii character and its color code by matching their hexa value. My problem is the hexa from 7-13 is not showing up.

```
.model small
.code
org 100h
s:jmp main
b dB 0h
d dB 000h
main proc


x:call color
mov ah,2
mov dl,b
int 21h
inc b
cmp b,14
jna x
int 20h

color proc
mov ah,9
mov al,''
mov bl,d
mov cx,1
int 10h
inc d
ret
color endp

main endp
end s
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the characters in that range don't have an image (glyph) to display, but are used as control characters, like tab and newline.

See this table http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I see but i tried outputting them alone and they showew up. For example i just used 0a hexa and its matching color code. The problem occurs when i try to output them with other hexa value. I mean when i want the output to show ascii characters and its color code from 0h-20h

Answer (score 0):

First, can you tell me where a class is being taught where the homework involves writing 16-bit x86 ASM and DOS software interrupts? I just think it's awesome that some schools care about teaching the classics. :-)

Next, I want to clarify what your program is doing: You're trying to showcase [all 16 colors in the BIOS color attribute table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_Color_Attributes), correct? And what characters do you want to print? As [Bo Persson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/597607/bo-persson) already answered, you can't print low ASCII characters because they are just not printable.

You are using 2 separate interrupts in your code and I think they might be conflicting. The first is [int 21h/ah = 02h](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02): write char to STDOUT. This is a DOS interrupt. The second is [int 10h/ah = 09h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0099.htm): write char and attribute on screen. This is a video interrupt and I think it's the one you want. Try relying on that second interrupt. Write 30h (ASCII '0') into al-- that should print different colored zeros.